# Magento override model class

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2
how to override
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/AdminOrder/Create.php
class in module ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

> Create a di.xml in etc/adminhtml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create" type="Vender\Module\Model\AdminOrder\CreateAdminOrder" />
</config>
```

> Create CreateAdminOrder.php in Vender\Module\Model\AdminOrder folder

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Model\AdminOrder;

class CreateAdminOrder extends Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create
{
    //call the construct function
    public function __construct(){}

    //overrider function and change
    public function initRuleData()
    {
        // Write a your logic
    }
}
```